# R: Verifying if any two character vectors are perfectly correlated

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to verify if any two character vectors, among several, are perfectly correlated, meaning that for each possible value of one vector, the corresponding value in another is always the same, like in this example:

```
a <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D")
b <- c("w", "w", "w", "w", "5", "x", "2", "2")
c <- c("A", "A", "A", "d", "B", "C", "D", "D")
```

I would like to be able to know that `a` and `b` are perfectly correlated.

Please note that these vectors could be much longer, and that we could have many more vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `identical` on the `match`

```
identical( match(a, unique(a)), match(b, unique(b)))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

If there are multiple `vector`s, place them in a `list`, loop through the `list`, do the `match`, `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector` and with `all`, we check if all the values are TRUE

```
all(Reduce(`==`, lapply(list(a, b), function(x) match(x, unique(x)))))
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

If we are looking for pairwise equality of vectors, use `combn`

```
res <- combn(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 2, FUN = function(x)  
   all(Reduce(`==`, lapply(mget(x, envir = .GlobalEnv), function(y) match(y, unique(y))))))
names(res) <- combn(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 2, FUN = paste, collapse="_")
res
#   a_b   a_c   b_c 
#  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Could this be applied to a situation where we would have more vectors, lets say a, b, c and d, and verifying if any two are perfectly correlated?

Comment: @arielle  You can place the `vectors` in a `list` and do `all(Reduce('==', lapply(list(a, b), function(x) match(x, unique(x)))))`

Comment: I am getting "Error: unexpected '==' in "all(Reduce(=="

Comment: @arielle I didn't quote earlier (used backquotes which was not seen in the comments).  Can you try the edited one now

Comment: I see, it is working to check if they are all perfectly correlated, but it does not tell if any two are correlated, I will edit my question. Sorry about that, I should have thought about this earlier

Comment: @arielle If it is any two, then you may need `combn`.  Anyway, your original question is based on two vectors and this is getting beyond the scope of the question

Comment: should I delete it and re-post? sorry about the trouble

Comment: @arielle  Updated the post.  Pleae check if that helps